# Why is there a difference in the output of pythonanywhere and local visual studio code?

Tags: python, django, audio, speech-recognition, pythonanywhere

I am trying to make a speech to text program in python and deploying it with django . On the same audio file I am getting different results when I try to run it on pythonanywhere and visual studio code

Here is my code :

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def aud():
    f = 'filepath/output.wav'
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    x = sr.AudioFile(f)
    with x as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
        mytext= r.recognize_google(audio)
    
    return(mytext.lower())
```

**VSC Output:**

```
"ok around better late than never ad-hoc"
```

**Pythonanywhere Output:**

```
"oakwood aren't naturally at home"
```

How can I get the same result ?

Comment: The version of `speech_recognition` are likely different. Can you `print(sr.__version__)`?

Comment: both are same  (ie 3.8.1)

Comment: According to their README speech_recognition package is "performing speech recognition, with support for several engines and APIs, online and offline". It must be using some different backed at some stage on your local machine and different on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: makes sense ... thanks